# ASP.NET Core on AWS Lambda - Data Protection keys store as Env Variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

NET Core web service, hosted on AWS Lambda, which requires built-in Cookie Authentication. I therefore need to share Data Protection key between multiple lambda instances.

I would like to save key either as environment variable in Lambda or through AWS Secrets Manager (or how exactly is it called)

Can I configure Data Protection to read key from Environment Variable? Has anyone done something like this yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the AWS DataProtection storage provider using SSM Parameter Store? https://github.com/aws/aws-ssm-data-protection-provider-for-aspnet

Comment: Thanks a lot Norm! I Have just implemented AWS DataProtection, but I found out it solves just a part of my problem. I have IdentityServer4 which needs X509 certificate and I am looking for an option how share such cert between lambdas. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: This is a separate question, use AWS Certificate Manager, upload Certificate. Load from ACM in Lambda Startup. Set the loaded Certificate to that. Original answer needs an upvote as its 100% correct and hard to find a solid answer too just based on the behavior seen in Lambdas and authentication, as I discovered late last night.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/sdk-get.html